# IE9 issue when I click one button it triggers all events of the other buttons?

Tags: jquery, onclick, internet-explorer-9

I have 4 buttons and they are outside of submit form? When I click one button it triggers all the click events of the other buttons. I saw this article, changed my input to button. It did not help, any suggestions?

My Page:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ReportQuestionaire", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SignupForm" }))
       {
           // code removed 
       }

 <button type="button" id="review_btn" onclick="reviewScreen();"></button>
            <button type="button" id="SaveAccount" onclick="SaveComplete();"></button>
            <button type="button" id="Next"></button>
            <button type="button" id="Previous"></button>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug javascript?

Comment: I used developer tools on chrome to view any errors..nothing

Answer (score 0):

Check your DOM structure to confirm that IE is not misunderstanding it and wrapping first button around next three.

Also, this question is not just jquery related.